# Is it possible to connect window cmd terminal with SecureCRT?

Tags: cmd

I'm using SecureCRT at windows 10.

And it's my SecureCRT version
Version 7.2.6 (x64 build 606)   -   Official Release - August 19, 2014

I want to open windows cmd terminal at SecureCRT.

How to I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is yes. But, you have to upgrade your SecureCRT software.

   Local shell sessions are supported in SecureCRT v8.7.x.

   You can reference the [offical release note](https://whatsnew.vandyke.com/category/products/securecrt/).

2. Open a local shell by [FILE] -> [Connect Local Shell] or press ALT+SHIFT+L

[image]

> **New in SecureCRT 8.7 (Official)**
>
> **Local shell session (Windows):**
>
> On Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 or later, you can open a local shell session within SecureCRT. A tabbed CMD or PowerShell session makes it easy to work on the local system without having to leave SecureCRT. Local shell was already supported on macOS and Linux.